# Android Dialog Box cuts rating bar

Tags: android, xml

I have a custom dialog box that serves as a rating window for items in my app. The dialog box has a title bar, a ratings bar, a text editor and two buttons. The title bar is dynamic and sets itself according to the item that is being rated. When the item has a "long" name, say atleast 15 characters, the ratings bar is display properly.

[image: The custom dialog box with a long title]

When the title has a short title, the ratings bar gets cut.

[image: custom dialog box with an incomplete rating bar]

I tried using a fixed size dialog box, but it looks terrible and things get misplaced.

Here is my XML for the dialog box:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/dim_foreground_material_light"
        android:text="Rate Spongy's Cafe"
        android:id="@+id/rateHeader"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/myPrimaryColor"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rateHeader"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
    <RatingBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ratingsBar"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:rating="5"
        style="@style/MyRatingBar"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rateHeader"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/rateHeader" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5.0"
        android:id="@+id/rateTV"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ratingsBar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/errorTV"
        android:text="Something Went Wrong. Please Try Again"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rateTV"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/errorColor"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_below="@+id/errorTV"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Write Your Review(200 Characters)"
        android:lines="5"
        android:id="@+id/reviewED"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/reviewED"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:background="@drawable/cart_button_selector"
            android:id="@+id/cancelRateBtn"
            android:textColor="@color/myPrimaryColor"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:textColor="@color/myPrimaryColor"
            android:background="@drawable/cart_button_selector"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/submitRateBtn"
            />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

The java code:

```
dialog = new Dialog(RateRestaurantActivity.this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.rate_dialog);
TextView titleTV = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.rateHeader);
final TextView rateTV = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.rateTV);
Button submitBtn = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.submitRateBtn);
Button cancelBtn = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelRateBtn);
RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar)dialog.findViewById(R.id.ratingsBar);
final EditText reviewED = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.reviewED);
titleTV.setText("Rate "+title);
dialog.show();
```

Please Help? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep your `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` of TextView  id `android:id="@+id/rateHeader"` to `fill_parent` or `match_parent`

and same for your rating Bar you can do!

so final code should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/dim_foreground_material_light"
        android:text="Rate Spongy's Cafe"
        android:id="@+id/rateHeader"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/myPrimaryColor"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rateHeader"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
    <RatingBar
        android:layout_width="fill_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ratingsBar"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:rating="5"
        style="@style/MyRatingBar"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rateHeader"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/rateHeader" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5.0"
        android:id="@+id/rateTV"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ratingsBar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/errorTV"
        android:text="Something Went Wrong. Please Try Again"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rateTV"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/errorColor"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_below="@+id/errorTV"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Write Your Review(200 Characters)"
        android:lines="5"
        android:id="@+id/reviewED"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/reviewED"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:background="@drawable/cart_button_selector"
            android:id="@+id/cancelRateBtn"
            android:textColor="@color/myPrimaryColor"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:textColor="@color/myPrimaryColor"
            android:background="@drawable/cart_button_selector"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/submitRateBtn"
            />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.However, I did not use `fill_parent` for the ratings bar because it added extra stars so that they fill the entire dialog window. So i just used it on the TextView. Thank you for your answer. :-)